# How do I model a diamond shaped extrusion on a cylinder but the whole thing has to be sub dividable

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

I'm trying to make a spiked ring with quad topology and it should be subdividable, been at it for 5 hours no luck. attached is the base of the shape.
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposition of topology:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you <3...